# Boolean Masking on a Pandas Dataframe where columns may not exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `compare` that looks like this:

| Resident | 1xdisc | 1xdisc_doc | conpark | parking | parking_doc | conmil | conmil_doc | pest | pest_doc | pet | pet1x | pet_doc | rent | rent_doc | stlc | storage | trash | trash_doc | water | water_doc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | -500 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1803 | 1803 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| Cheldone | -500 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 1.25 | 1.25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1565 | 1565 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| Dieu | -300 | -300 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1372 | 1372 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 18 | 0 | 0 |

Here is the dataframe in a form that can be copied and pasted:

`,Resident,1xdisc,1xdisc_doc,conpark,parking,parking_doc,conmil,conmil_doc,pest,pest_doc,pet,pet1x,pet_doc,rent,rent_doc,stlc,storage,trash,trash_doc,water,water_doc 0,Acacia,0,0,0,0,0,0,-500,3.0,3.0,0,0,70,2067,2067,0,0,15,15,0,0 1,ashley,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3.0,3.0,0,0,0,2067,2067,0,0,15,15,0,0 2,Sheila,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1574,1574,0,0,0,0,0,0 3,Brionne,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1787,1787,0,0,0,0,0,0 4,Danielle,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1422,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 5,Nmesomachi,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1675,1675,0,0,0,0,0,0 6,Doaa,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1306,1306,0,0,0,0,0,0 7,Reynaldo,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1685,1685,0,0,0,0,0,0 8,Shajuan,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1768,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 9,Dalia,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,1596,1596,0,0,0,0,0,0`

I want to create another dataframe using boolean masking that only contains rows where there are mismatches various sets of columns. For example, where `parking` doesn't match `parking_doc` or `conmil` doesn't match `conmil_doc`.

Here is the code I am using currently:

```
nonmatch = compare[((compare['1xdisc']!=compare['1xdisc_doc']) & 
                 (compare['conpark']!=compare['1xdisc']))
               | (compare['rent']!=compare['rent_doc']) 
               | (compare['parking']!=compare['parking_doc']) 
               | (compare['trash']!=compare['trash_doc'])
               | (compare['pest']!=compare['pest_doc'])
               | (compare['stlc']!=compare['stlc_doc'])
               | (compare['pet']!=compare['pet_doc'])
               |(compare['conmil']!=compare['conmil_doc'])
              ]
```

The problem I'm having is that some columns may not always exist, for example `stlc_doc` or `pet_doc`. How do   I select rows with mismatches, but only check for mismatches for particular columns if the columns exist?

Comment: please post the dataframe as copy pasteable code

Comment: @Gulzar I added the dataframe in copy pasteable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column names doesn't always exist, you can either add the columns  that doesn't exist which I don't think will be a good idea since you will have to replicate the corresponding columns which will eventually increase the size of the dataframe.

So, another approach might be to filter the column names themselves and take only the column pairs that exists:

Given DataFrame:

```py
>>> df.head(3)
  Resident  1xdisc  1xdisc_doc  conpark  parking  parking_doc  conmil  conmil_doc  pest  pest_doc  pet  pet1x  pet_doc  rent  rent_doc  stlc  storage  trash  trash_doc  water  water_doc 
0   Acacia       0           0        0        0            0       0        -500   3.0       3.0    0      0       70  2067      2067     0        0     15         15      0           0
1   ashley       0           0        0        0            0       0           0   3.0       3.0    0      0        0  2067      2067     0        0     15         15      0           0
2   Sheila       0           0        0        0            0       0           0   0.0       0.0    0      0        0  1574      1574     0        0      0          0      0           0
```

Take out the columns pairs:

```py
>>> maskingCols = [(col[:-4], col) for col in df if col[:-4] in df and col.endswith('_doc')]
maskingCols
[('1xdisc', '1xdisc_doc'), ('parking', 'parking_doc'), ('conmil', 'conmil_doc'), ('pest', 'pest_doc'), ('pet', 'pet_doc'), ('rent', 'rent_doc'), ('trash', 'trash_doc')]
```

Now that you have the column pairs, you can create the expression required to mask the dataframe.

```py
>>> "|".join(f"(df['{col1}'] != df['{col2}'])" for col1, col2 in maskingCols)

"(df['1xdisc'] != df['1xdisc_doc'])|(df['parking'] != df['parking_doc'])|(df['conmil'] != df['conmil_doc'])|(df['pest'] != df['pest_doc'])|(df['pet'] != df['pet_doc'])|(df['rent'] != df['rent_doc'])|(df['trash'] != df['trash_doc'])"
```

You can simply pass this expression string to `eval` function to evaluate it.

```py
>>> eval("|".join(f"(df['{col1}'] != df['{col2}'])" for col1, col2 in maskingCols))
```

You can add other criteria other than this masking:

```py
>>> eval("|".join(f"(df['{col1}'] != df['{col2}'])" for col1, col2 in maskingCols)) | ((df['1xdisc']!=df['1xdisc_doc']) & (df['conpark']!=df['1xdisc']))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
9    False
dtype: bool
```

You can use it to get your desired dataframe:

```py
>>> df[eval("|".join(f"(df['{col1}'] != df['{col2}'])" for col1, col2 in maskingCols)) | ((df['1xdisc']!=df['1xdisc_doc']) & (df['conpark']!=df['1xdisc']))]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
 Resident  1xdisc  1xdisc_doc  conpark  parking  parking_doc  conmil  conmil_doc  pest  pest_doc  pet  pet1x  pet_doc  rent  rent_doc  stlc  storage  trash  trash_doc  water  water_doc 
0    Acacia       0           0        0        0            0       0        -500   3.0       3.0    0      0       70  2067      2067     0        0     15         15      0           0
4  Danielle       0           0        0        0            0       0           0   0.0       0.0    0      0        0  1422         0     0        0      0          0      0           0
8   Shajuan       0           0        0        0            0       0           0   0.0       0.0    0      0        0  1768         0     0        0      0          0      0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pandas expert, so there might be a simpler, library way to do this, but here's a relatively Pythonic, adaptable implementation:

```py
mask = True
for col_name in df.columns:
    # inefficient but readable, could get this down
    # to O(n) with a better data structure
    if col_name + '_doc' in df.columns: 
        mask = mask & (df[col_name] != df[col_name + '_doc'])

non_match = df[mask]
```